# how can I get the data from localStorage to show in homePosts vue.js compositions API

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vue-composition-api, v-for, v-model

I'm doing a simple blog app to practice vue.js. I'm using composition API. I have stored data that get filled in in a form. This data I want to print out in another component `homePosts` where you can see the written blogpost with writer, headline and blogtext. I have used v-model, stored data to `localStorage`, in `homePosts` I have used v-for and `{{ }}` syntax to get data. But nothing shows in `homePosts`.
Can someone please see what im missing.

**writePost.vue**

```js
    <template>
      <div>
        <form class="form">
          <label for="writer">Writer name: </label>
          <input v-model="newWriter" type="text" max="500" />
          <br />
          <label for="img">Select image:</label>
          <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*" />
          <br />
          <label for="headline">Headline </label>
          <input v-model="newHeadline" type="text" max="500" />
          <label>Your blogtext: </label>
          <textarea v-model="newNote" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="30"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" @click="addNote" class="button"><router-link to="/homePosts" class="link">Post blog</router-link></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    
    const newNote = ref("");
    const newWriter = ref("");
    const newHeadline = ref("");
    const notes = ref([]);
    
    
    const addNote = () => {
      notes.value.push({
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
        text: newNote.value,
        writer: newWriter.value,
        headline: newHeadline.value,
      });
    
      addLocalStorage(notes)
    
    };
    const addLocalStorage = (notes) => {
        
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));    
    }
    </script>
```

**homePosts.vue**

```js
    <template>
    <div class="post-container">
        <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
        <div class="post-mini-container" > 
            <div  class="post" v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
                <!-- <img class="img-post" src="@/assets/person1.jpg"> -->
                <p class="writer"> {{ note.writer }}</p>
                <p class="headline"> {{ note.headline }}</p>
                <p class="blog-text" > {{ note.text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
     export default {
        name: 'homePosts'
     }
     
    </script>
```

Comment: Where do you call the homePosts Component and where do you take the Data out of the LocalStorage for it. Keep in mind that the localStorage can't contain any reactive Data. Your app might not know that the Data has changed.

Comment: should the two components communicate in a way? what can I use?

Comment: If you want to have Components communicate together take a look at 
pinia or checkout provide/inject. 
Pinia is a store that allows "global" communication within the Vue Instance. 
Provide/Inject allows communication through a parent, while the parent is providing a reactive property and the children can read (and write) to that property by injecting it :)

Comment: or can i get data from local storage and write it out in homeposts?

Comment: Yes you could. But you would need to either have a communication between the Components that homepots knows that new Data is in the LocalStorage or you need to try to read from it in a loop (def. not recommended) this would be bad for performance. Going for Communication between them is the better approach.
if you want to save Data anyway to the localstorage you can try to build a small sync.

Comment: btw. you might also want to go for vueuse's useStorage function that gives you an reactive LocalStorage:
https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/

Comment: thank you ill try vue use storage and try to get homeposts to recieve the data from there.

Comment: I dont really understand everything you wrote :/ If I stay with normal localStorage, can I not in some way get the data to come out on homePosts that I have written in writePosts?

Comment: Well yes you could. But you would need to check if the data has changed in an Interval because the localStorage is not reactive. Vue won't know if data there changes.
useStorage helps you with this because then it does know when it changes :)

Comment: okey i start with localStorage and learn that first :)) how can I get the data from localStorage to show in homePosts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your ref already parsing the existing items in your localStorage.

```js
const notes = ref(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes') ?? '[]');
```

Or better yet, use a computed getter/setter:

```js
const notes = computed({
  get: () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes') ?? '[]'),
  set: (value) => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(value))
  }
});
```

Or even better, take a look at [vueUse/useLocalStorage](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/)

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches that you can follow, "event bus" or "pinia / vuex".
i'll explain how you can implement event bus

(you can check this post for inspiration: https://medium.com/@certosinolab/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-3-425aae8c21a6)

1. Add global event bus

- install mit: `npm install --save mitt`
- go to your main.ts / main.js and add the global property

```
    import mitt from 'mitt';

    const dispatcher = mitt();
    const app = createApp(App);
    app.config.globalProperties.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    app.mount('#app');
```

2. update "script" content in writePost.vue component

   ```
   <script setup>
   import { ref , getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

       const app = getCurrentInstance(); 
       const dispatcher= app?.appContext.config.globalProperties.dispatcher;

   const newNote = ref("");
   const newWriter = ref("");
   const newHeadline = ref("");
   const notes = ref([]);
   const addNote = () => {
     notes.value.push({
       id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
       text: newNote.value,
       writer: newWriter.value,
       headline: newHeadline.value,
     });
   // emit notes
   dispatcher.emit("updateNotes" , notes);

     addLocalStorage(notes)

   };
   const addLocalStorage = (notes) => {
       localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
       JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));    
   }
   </script>
   ```
3. update "script" content in homePosts.vue component

```
         <script>
             export default {
                name: 'homePosts',
                data() {
                  return {notes: []}
                },
                mounted() {
                  this.notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes") ?? "[]");
    
                  this.dispatcher.on("updateNotes" , (notes) => {
    this.notes = notes ?? [];
    })
                },
                beforeDestroy() {
                   this.dispatcher.off("updateNotes");
                },
             }
             
            </script>
```